# Lists with the same name inside lists

Tags: python, list, split, for-in-loop

In the following setup:

```
a = raw_input("Enter 2 sided equation: ")

sides = a.split(" = ")

for side in sides:
    numbers = side.split(" ")

print numbers
```

When the following code is printed, the result is:

```
Enter 2 sided equation: 5 +3 +7 -2 = 12 +6 -5
["12", "+6", "-5"]
```

**How can I avoid making 2 lists (called "numbers")** so i can work with different sums?

Comment: What should the result be?

Comment: Result should either be `["5", "+3", "+7", "-2"]` and `["12", "+6", "-5"]` or `["5", "+3", "+7", "-2", "12", "+6", "-5"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to avoid that. You just need to store both:

Either you do

```
total = []
for side in sides:
    numbers = side.split(" ")
    total.append(numbers)
```

or you shortcut this with a list comprehension:

```
total = [side.split(" ") for side in sides]
```